# What would be the point of leaving the migration message from Guitar.SE (after a few weeks)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, guitars, migration

I expect that we would suppress it as the site no longer exists...

Comment: They're gone, see http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/215/bug-migrated-from-guitars-link-goes-to-guitars-which-redirects-to-the-wrong-m/247#247

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you're saying, but: guitars.stackexchange.com currently redirects here. The message is for users who don't know what's going on when they arrive at this site. It won't stay there for long.

**Edit:** You mean this message?

[image: picture]

I suppose it might make sense to remove the link after a time, but given that the owner may be a "dead" user it's useful for explanatory purposes.

Comment: I think he's referring to the message that appears on the question page below the body. HAH! As it happens, if you click the link (which points to where the question used to exist on guitars.SE), it redirects to music, but uses the guitars.SE question ID number to match to an ID number on _music_.SE, and then displays the page of whichever question matches with _that._

Comment: @NReilingh Ah, thanks for the explanation. That behavior is definitely wrong! I'll made a `[bug]` post about it: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/215/bug-migrated-from-guitars-link-goes-to-guitars-which-redirects-to-the-wrong-m

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be useful to leave the message for a time. It's unlikely to cause confusion, and it may be instructive. Other SE sites are considering merging, and showing the process in this way is nicely transparent. Yes, it's a little bit of clutter, but I don't think that's much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely useful to keep information that it came from Guitars.SE, but the link should be removed (not fixed, as it would point to the same question you're currently looking at). Also it would be good to have a note that the original site does not longer exist, and all guitar related questions should be asked here at music.SE.